# Javascript: iterate columns and output that to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a month of JS experience so I'm mostly useless beyond `Hello, World!` but Schmedtmann's course on Udemy has been really awesome. Here's what I'm trying to do:

User enters data where there will be `n` columns, with two rows of a start number and finish number, then the next column incremented ++1. Like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5
1   101 201 301 401
100 200 300 400 500
```

The user will enter in number of columns, the starting number, and the range of the sequence. So something like this:

```
// total number of columns, ex "5"
let totalColumn = Number(totalColumnE1.value);

// the starting column number, ex. "3"
let columnNumber = Number(columnNumberE1.value);

// the start of the sequence, ex. "101"
let number = Number(numberE1.value);

// the range of each sequence, ex. "100"
let range = Number(rangeE1.value);
```

Would produce something like this:

```
3   4   5   6   7
101 201 301 401 501
200 300 400 500 600
```

This is where my brain freezes. How do I iterate this thing?

```
if (columnNumber < totalColumn) {

let output = `<tr><td>Column ${columnNumber}</td></tr>
              <tr><td>${number}</td></tr>
              <tr><td>${number + range}</td></tr>`;

  outputEl.innerHTML = output;
  }
```

In my limited understanding, it feels like I need to create an index or counter to increment this, or maybe an array, or maybe both? Can this be done in Vanilla JS?

FWIW, I eventually want to export this to excel, hence the columns, so I don't know if I need to consider that as well before moving forward. Thank you!

Comment: try first to create an array with 3 rows of n columns. then output it to html

Comment: I think your missing the parameter for how many rows. You'll need a `for` loop that will create each row on each iteration there should be another `for` loop nested within the first `for` loop. This `for` loop will create all of the cells within each row. Please google "js table for loops" or a some variation of this search term.

Comment: @ITgoldman I don't know why, but it makes more sense to me thinking of an array with n rows and 3 columns

Comment: it's probably the same thing. because the html and the csv it is more natural for me to use rows

Comment: @GrafiCode yes for some reason (mostly inexperience) it's hard for me to think in terms of columns but with rows it seems easier for my brain to break down into logical parts.

Comment: @Ringthane I know what you mean. This thing happens to me also when plotting coordinates, I always end up switching `x` with `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create HTML, or just an output that you can use in Excel? If Excel, then you want to use CSV, which is also easier to create than all of those HTML elements. https://www.howtogeek.com/348960/what-is-a-csv-file-and-how-do-i-open-it/

I don't quite follow your "how do I iterate" question. You need to use a for loop that iterates over the values in the input. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement

Without writing the answer for you, does that make sense?

Comment: Re: HTML and Excel, I'm trying to do both. The HTML output is going to be an on-screen guide for the user as they're creating this data, which will eventually be imported into Excel.

And yes, broadly, I understand this now. I was being stupid and forgot the very important loop that continues to loop through and iterate. Thank you!

Comment: Then I'd start by creating a 2D array to store your table via for loop, then iterate over the array to create both the HTML and later the CSV. A 2D array is an array of arrays, which is essentially a table. Do it with nested for loops, where one loop's index is the column, and the other is the row. Feel free to ask more questions if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

Solution of this problem seems to be array of arrays, where each row can be considered a separate array that follows or gets generated using a pattern. Then the resulting arrays can be used to create an html table.

But its unclear how many rows you want to generate because the question says 2 and the sample codes shows 3, but however the solution can be can be scaled up to n number of rows.

*Please do read comments in the code.

```js
// output array that will contain arrays of sequences
let outputArray = [];

// user input number of columns
let totalColNo = 5;
// user input column start number
let colStartNo = 3;
// user input range sequence start number
let rangeStartNo = 101;
// user input range for sequence
let rangeOfRange = 100;

// 1st sequence, col start
let colStartSequence = [];
// 2nd sequence, range
let rangeSequence = [];

// generate 1st sequence of arrays i.e. [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for (let i = 1; i <= totalColNo; i++) {
  colStartSequence.push(colStartNo);
  colStartNo += 1;
}

// generate 2nd sequence of arrays i.e. [101, 201, 301, 401, 501]
for (let i = 1; i <= totalColNo; i++) {
  rangeSequence.push(rangeStartNo);
  rangeStartNo += rangeOfRange;
}

// pushing arrays to output array
outputArray = [colStartSequence, rangeSequence];
// console.log(outputArray);

// Html
// select parent id
const parentId = document.getElementById("dynamicTable");

// a function that will accept our 'outputArray' and create and populate the table
function createTable(tableData) {
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  const tBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  // number of rows will be created according to 'outputArray.length'
  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    // number of columns will be created according to 'totalColNo' variable
    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      const cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tBody);
  table.border = 1;
  parentId.appendChild(table);
}

createTable(outputArray);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="dynamicTable"></div>
</div>
```